# Why root is always null in Binary Tree

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

I am trying to implement insert operation on Binary search Tree(BST).I have a function called `insert` and `push`.Whenever a value is given to insert , `insert()` function is called.If root is Null(initially) it will be inserted.If root is not null then from insert() another function `push()` will be called  to insert the value.But for me root always remain null.I used a string "i am here" to check and every time i try to insert a new data this string gets printed .That's how i know root remains NULL.What is the problem behind this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct node {

    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node *right;
};
void insert(struct node *root,int value);
void push(struct node *temp,struct node *newNode);
struct node *root;
int main(){
    root = NULL;
    int option,value;
    for(;;){
       printf("Please select an option from below : \n");
       printf("1 for insert\n");
       printf("2 for search\n");
       printf("please enter your option : ");
       scanf("%d",&option);
       printf("\n");
       switch(option){
           case 1:
               printf("you choose to insert\n");
               printf("input your value :");
               scanf("%d",&value);
               insert(root,value);
               printf("\n");
               break;
           default:
               break;

       }
    }
}

void insert(struct node *root,int value){
    struct node *newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    temp = root;
    if(root==NULL){
         printf("i am here");
         root = newNode;  // enter first node
    }else{

        push(temp,newNode);
    }
}
void push(struct node *temp,struct node *newNode){
    printf("others");
    if(temp==NULL){
         temp = newNode;
    }else{
         if(temp->data > newNode->data){
              push(temp->left,newNode);
         }else{
            push(temp->right,newNode);
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: `root = newNode;` and `temp = newNode;` do not alter their values in the calling function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program have two variables with the name `root`. The first is the global variable the other is local to the function insert. That's why the global variable can't be changed in the the function `insert`.

You can change the interface like

```
struct node* insert(struct node *root,int value);
```

and use the function that way:

```
root = insert(root,value);
```

Several other methods exists to change the global variable, e.g. use that interface:

```
void insert(struct node **root,int value);
```

Comment: thnx for your reply..I think i need to study more about this topic :)